# Azure Maps geocoding interface

Tags: azure, azure-maps

where can I find interface description of Azure Maps geocoding API? I need basically description of response. [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address) has nothing.

Comment: Please see Azure Maps Geocoding API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress

Answer (score 0):

I found some: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/searchservice/getsearchaddressstructured
But description is very poor. For example:

dist - number - Dist property

If we're talking about a distance we basically want to know between what the distance. It's missing there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, for the [Geocoding API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress) and the [Geocoding Structured API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured) the "dist" is the distance in meters from the "geo-bias" (part of summary) in the response.

For [Geocoding API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress) "geo-bias" is the "lat/lon" bias you specify in the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can post user voice about the document via mini window at the right bottom in the page. Microsoft would monitor it and improve the documents.

[image]

Another option is, you can visit the help and support center to create or track a support ticket and monitor health in Azure Portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Maps documentation is being improved. Much of Azure Maps is currently built on top of TomTom. You can find more detailed response interface details here: https://developer.tomtom.com/online-search/online-search-documentation-geocoding/structured-geocode

That said, there doesn't seem to be much detail on the `dist` property. This property would make more sense in the context of reverse geocoding, where the address returned is often near the specified coordinate not, not at the exact specified coordinate.